# MySQL funnel multiple ANDs

Tags: mysql, sql

With the below MySQL query, I would like to match where `page` is both `/signup` and then later down in the userflow `/confirm`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as `total` FROM (

    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t.user_id) AS `visitors`
    FROM `tracks` t
    JOIN `user_details` u ON u.id=t.user_id AND u.site_id=t.site_id
    WHERE t.site_id='334565'
    AND (t.page = '/signup' AND t.page = '/confirm')
    AND t.timestamp BETWEEN '2015-01-23 00:00:00' AND '2015-04-30 23:59:59'
    GROUP BY t.user_id, t.track_id
) as a
```

The main problem with this query, is that MySQL doesn't work the way I'm trying to use it (incorrectly).
The other problem is that the returned order would potentially be incorrect, so also needs to be in the specified order.

Maybe this query needs to be done completely differently, but I'm not sure I'm on the right track.

Has anyone done this before or is there a better way to get the job done?

Please note that the above WHERE clause could match more than just `page` and could be anything such as `t.referrer` or `u.somethingelse`

Another example would be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as `total` FROM (

    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t.user_id) AS `visitors`
    FROM `tracks` t
    JOIN `user_details` u ON u.id=t.user_id AND u.site_id=t.site_id
    WHERE t.site_id='334565'
    AND (u.browser = 'chrome' AND t.referrer_host = 'google.com' AND t.page = '/confirm' and t.page = '/preferences')
    AND t.timestamp BETWEEN '2015-01-23 00:00:00' AND '2015-04-30 23:59:59'
    GROUP BY t.user_id, t.track_id
) as a
```

Each of the `u.browser`, `t.referrer_host`, `t.page` are goals and I am `trying` to show them all together as a funnel. Kind of how an analytics program would do it.

Comment: (t.page = '/signup' OR t.page = '/confirm'), and having count(distinct t.page) = 2

Comment: @jarlh it needs to match both in the recordset, not return 1 row with either. (user flow)

Comment: @smftre you need to include your table schemas, and some data. It's a little hard to grok as it stands

Comment: your `t.page` AND clause makes it impossible to match ANYTHING in the db. you're basically saying "find records that are simultaneously an elephant and a pack of chewing gum". You need to use `OR` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is tracking visitors to web pages (not a tough assumption to make), with each url / page endpoint having its own entry in the tracking table.

In order to find users who have hit both pages, you need to join the tracking table to itself. Something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t1.user_id) AS `visitors`
FROM `tracks` t1
JOIN `user_details` u ON u.id=t1.user_id AND u.site_id=t1.site_id
join `tracks` t2 on t1.site_id = t2.site_id and u.id = t2.user_id and t1.track_id <> t2.track_id
WHERE t1.site_id='334565'
AND (t1.page = '/signup' AND t2.page = '/confirm')
AND t1.timestamp BETWEEN '2015-01-23 00:00:00' AND '2015-04-30 23:59:59'
```

I don't think there's any need for grouping, as I think you just want the distinct number of visitors that have signed up, and then confirmed.

Comment: Would that mean that I would have to join another table each time I added a `goal`? This looks to be a very under-performant method. Am I approaching this incorrectly?

Comment: joining isn't a bad thing. but if you want to track flow (basically, hierarchical data), then yes it's basically how you have to do it.  if on the other hand you dont care about the order of the visits, you can do it a little simpler